# Is it true that Ghatotkacha had the Ravana bow as well as demons from the Ravana clan?

Tags: mahabharata, ravana, rakshasa, ghatotkacha

Quora answers, like [this](https://www.quora.com/Who-was-Ghatotkacha-What-was-role-of-Gatotkacha-in-Mahabharata-War) claim that Ghatotkacha had Ravana's bow, demons of Ravana's clan and even his floats. Is this true?

Comment: Which answer is claiming that? I can't see any answer stating that.